# Cakephp 2.4 JSHelper Confirm to use Dialog instead of Javascript Confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I am using Cakephp 2.4 with bootstrap I have the following code which generates an AJAX Link correctly

```
echo $this->Js->link('Delete', array('controller' => 'albums', 'action' => 
'delete',  $id), array('update' => '#success', 
'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to Delete'));
```

The "confirm" generates the Javascript Confirm Box. I am looking to replace this with the bootstrap dialog box. I have tried using "before" to open the dialog box successfully but returning false from the "before" callback function does not stop the AJAX Call from 
aborting.

Any clue on how this can be done with JSHelper or would I have to write custom JS Code for it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read up on what [Js->link()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper%3a%3alink) does? You don't need to pass `confirm` to the options if you don't want it.

Also have a look at what JS code the helper produces, if you can't "fix" from the helper to do what you want then you can always create a simple link with `Html->link()` and add JS events to it (or extend the helper).

But remember that `JsHelper` is a simple helper for the most profound JS framework functions. While it is perfectly fine to use it, I don't like to use PHP to create JS code, it can make a mess in the long run.